# Why doesn't BeanCopier work in copying properties?

Tags: java, spring

I want use BeanCopier to do the property copying between the following two porous

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@TableName("t_order")
public class Order extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
    private Long userId;
    private Integer amount;
    private Long productId;
}
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderDTO {
    private Long userId;
    private Integer amount;
    private Long productId;
}
```

for the following codes,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order order = Order.builder().productId(3333L).userId(9999L).amount(32).build();
        OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO();
        BeanCopier orderCopier = BeanCopier.create(Order.class, OrderDTO.class, false);
        orderCopier.copy(order, orderDTO, null);
        JSONUtils.toJSONString(orderDTO);
    }
```

the properties of orderDTO are not set, the fields of `orderDTO` are all null, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ohh there is simple thing missing , please add getters and setters , BeanCopier internally uses ReflectUtils to find getters and setters.

Please try and add those and then test.

There also a  alternative -

you can simple use Spring's BeanUtils and it's copyProperties - there are multiple options available

[Spring BeanUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html)

You can simply use it as

```
 BeanUtils.copyProperties( sourceBean , targetBean );
```

You can find different examples [HERE](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-framework-beanutils.html)

Comment: Hi @lily , can you please show me the code way you are instantiating BeanCopier , how are you creating it

Comment: corrected the answer , there is simple thing missing :) , let me know if it works